# Change title of button

Tags: ios, swift, uialertcontroller, uialertaction

I have an `alertController` with a `button` in it. Here's how I created the `button`:

```
var myButton : UIAlertAction!

// Later...
self.myButton = UIAlertAction(title: "myButton", style: .Default, handler: {action -> Void in
   self.myButton.title = "✔︎\(myButton)"
})
```

After the button get's selected, I want to add a "✔︎" at the beginning of the title. (As you can see in the last line of code above.) When I try doing that, I get the following error:

> Cannot assign to the result of this expression

What can I do to fix that? If `myButtons` title is `read-only`, then is there a valid workaround to it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is not about the "✔︎". It's because of `myButton`. It means nothing to assign a `UIAlertAction` to `String`. That's how you get the error.